# If AWS file upload Access Control List (ACL) is not 'public-read', how can I read it from client (React/Nextjs)

Tags: security, amazon-s3, next.js, file-upload, acl

There are some private file I need to upload AWS without **public-read** access, yet I also want to view the file (using URL) from my client (Reactjs/Nextjs) in a protected route. How can I achieve this?

**The exact scenario**: I need to post a PDF from my backend to AWS without public-read access (ACL), in the meantime I want to show that PDF in react-pdf in a protected route.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.

Your app can generate them locally, without requiring an API call to AWS, but they need to know an Access Key and Secret Key that has permission to access the object.

This way, objects remain private but you can provide a link that can still retrieve them. The link times-out after a defined period of time.